# WCF - How to return a value when the method is void

Tags: c#, wcf

Case: I have a void method that inserts data and does a bunch of stuff but recently  I was given a requirement that this exposed method in the service needs to return a value

What options do I have?
Pretty sure I need to refactor this but how or which approach?

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    void InsertPerson(string Name, string LastName, string Income, string Address)
```

Method looks like this:

```
    public void InsertPerson(string Name, string LastName, string Income, string Address)
    {
       try
       {
          Name = (Name == null) ? "" : Name ;
          LastName = (LastName  == null) ? "" : LastName ;
          Income = (Income== null) ? "" : Income;
          Address = (Address== null) ? "" : Address;

          //bunch of Procedures, DataSets and Functions
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         StoredProcedures.InsertLog(ex.ToString());
       }
    }
```

Solution needed: let's say that the procedures calculate the income and determine that the person is not fit for a loan, **I need to let know the caller in this same method that the person is not suitable for a loan** say for example with some additional parameter called `HighRisk` that returns 1 or 0

**Edit:**
Found a solution it was quite simple I just changed the `void` to a `List<T>` and made a class that returned the whole structure like so

```
List<Person> PersonInfo = new List<Person>();
DataSet ds = StoredProcedures.PersonSelect(Name, LastName);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   Person PersonData = new Person();
   PersonData.SuitableForLoan = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SuitableForLoan"].ToString();
   PersonInfo.Add(PersonData);
}
return PersonInfo;
```

edit 2: I don't understand why my question is being downvoted, I hate this place so much now I remember why I didn't want to make another account

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `void` rather than say `bool`?

Comment: Because a `bool` only returns stuff I needed to send and return at the same time, found a solution  will update the question with edit

Answer (score 4):

Well, the simple answer here would be: change the API - perhaps returning an enum instead of `void`, to indicate the success or failure reason. Note that this is a breaking change, however, so you can't do that unless you are happy to deploy clients and servers *at the same time* to match this API. If you can't break the API, you'll have to add a new method with a return value, and migrate clients to use the new method - leaving the old method for older clients to use until they are updated.

You could also perhaps hack it in with headers of some kind, but that's a terrible idea in most cases and will only make things more confused than they already are.